# db_select pager query orderBy signed int

Tags: database

I have an INT 'weight' field for some nodes that runs -20 through to +20 and want to order the nodes so that -20 is at the top, but, as far as I can tell I'm getting them in string order.  I've tried

```
  $query->addField('w', 'field_weight_value', 'weight');

  $result = $query
    ->limit(10)
    ->orderBy('CAST(w.field_weight_value AS SIGNED)', 'ASC')
    ->execute();
```

But that makes no difference, I still get 0 appearing above -10.  I'm using db_select so that I can use the `PagerDefault` extension.  I could just change the 'weight' field to be all positive, but that seems like a fail!

I think the problem might be it's always evaluated as a string even though the table column is type INT, if I perform the same query as db_query, e.g.

```
  $result = db_query('SELECT n.nid, n.title, w.field_weight_value 
    FROM {node} n 
    ORDER BY w.field_weight_value ASC', array(':nid' => $nid));
```

I get the results I expect.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `AS SIGNED INTEGER`?

Comment: Shouldn't that be sorted by `ASC`if you want the smallest weights at the top?

Comment: @Clive I believe the SIGNED alone is correct - see the MYSQL docs - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: @berliner - correct -edited for that.